# Gradle: 'archives' artifacts not populated to 'default' configuration

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to write a simple gradle file that publishes a pre-built jar archive:

```
apply plugin: 'base'

artifacts {
  archives file('some.jar')
}

task q << {
  println project.configurations.archives.allArtifacts*.file
  println project.configurations.default.allArtifacts*.file
}
```

However, as `gradle q` shows, `some.jar` only gets added to the `archives` configuration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

As the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) shows, **`archives` configuration has no relationship to `default` configuration**.

If you need so, you need to explicitly define it.

Comment: I think it's actually [supposed to](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6a42a3675bb04de97f9531b1ef53d4cd194e4054/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/BasePlugin.java#L154) include `archives` (and other configurations) artifacts thanks to BasePlugin. See also [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html): "_The archives configuration is the standard configuration to assign your artifacts to_"