# Gradle is not publishing custom jar artifact

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle build that must publish a pre-built jar file as an artifact. By some reason it is not being picked up. Here's a simplified version to reproduce it:

folder contents:

```
settings.gradle
build.gradle
some.jar
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'some'
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'foo.bar'
version = '1.0'

task copyPrebuilt(type: Copy) {
  from(projectDir) {
    include 'some.jar'
    rename 'some', "some-$version"
  }
  into distsDir
}

artifacts {
  // should be 'archives'?
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068090/gradle-archives-artifacts-not-populated-to-default-configuration
  'default' (file("$distsDir/some-${version}.jar")) {
    name 'some'
    type 'jar'
    builtBy copyPrebuilt
  }
}
```

`some-1.0.jar` is not copied to `~/.m2/repository/foo/bar/some/1.0` by `gradle publishToMavenLocal`

any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get something published is to define a publication object:

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'foo.bar'
version = '1.0'

task copyPrebuilt(type: Copy) {
    from(projectDir) {
        include 'some.jar'
        rename 'some', "some-$version"
    }
    into buildDir
}

publishToMavenLocal.dependsOn copyPrebuilt

publishing {
    publications {
        prebuilt(MavenPublication) {
            artifact file("$buildDir/some-${version}.jar")
        }
    }
}
```

This code makes `publishToMavenLocal` task install some-1.0.jar to the local maven repository.